# Add to cart form error: page reloads

Tags: expresso-store

when i add to cart page reloads but cart is still empty.

htaccess:

RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

```
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you maybe post some template code? and explain how you are adding to the cart? is this a normal link, is it AJAX? Do any errors show in the console? What does template debugging show?